# How to play all songs I own by an artist in itunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

After I upgraded iTunes to 12.5.3.17, when I click on an artist it only shows the albums of that artist. It does not show the songs that I own of that artist from various compilations. If I click "Shuffle All" it will not ever play or show the extra songs I have of that artist. The mp3s by this artist which are not on their albums but are correctly tagged to this particular artist under the "artist" field in the "get info" window (it is not set to various artists) of each mp3.

I have the same problem on my iPhone now after upgrading. There's no way to play or see the song I want at all besides searching for its exact name. The compilation album that it's on doesn't even show up in the all albums list, nor in the albums list of the song's artist. Also the song doesn't show up anywhere in the "songs" list of supposedly all my songs, which used to be sorted alphabetically by the names of all my songs.

Comment: Are you using list view and the top column browser?

Answer (score -1):

tap on Songs
tap on Sort - sort by Artist

Answer (score -1):

The new update doesn't allow to play all the songs from the same artist.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info. For example, do you have a reference or source you can cite to backup your answer? Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.